# Understanding an error message while writing code for a Fibonacci program

Tags: python, fibonacci

My apologies in advance should I butcher any Python vocabulary, this is my first programming class and we are not permitted to post or share our code. I will do my best to explain the problem.

I am defining my function as variable one and variable two.  I then gave values to both variables.  I used a for statement with a range value; created a new variable to handle the sum of the two previous Fib. values; and redefine my original variables for the program to iterate through until I reached my maximum.

I am receiving an error message:
`<function appendNextFib at 0x01FB14B0>`

I cannot find an explanation for what the error message means.  From either the message itself or from what I have written, does the fatal flaw jump out at anyone?

Comment: Upvoted for a well-written, descriptive question that shows you're making an effort rather than just saying "gimme-teh-codez".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke your function, you have to use parens: `appendNextFib()`.  It looks like you simply used `appendNextFib`, which would show you its value, which is that function object.

Comment: Two hours I have sat here, and it was that simple.  Thank you!

Comment: If you really want to thank me, accept the answer! Linda? D'oh... :(

Comment: Had to find the "boy am I happy to accept the answer button" ;)
Lesson learned, mistake not to be repeated.
Seriously....thank you all for such quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally think you may be stressing too much about the sharing of your code, a recursive solution to the problem is a lot more logical and would help you out if your issue is caught up in the declaration of variables.

the recursive solution would look like

```
def fib(n):
    base case:
         return val
    base case:
         return val
    else:
         return recursive call
```

Without trying to give too much away I hope this makes sense.

edit: just read that you had included the function id in your initial post, sorry for the confusion this may cause